# Get next page in get_posts

Tags: plugin-development, query-posts

I need to iterate posts list because I need to know how many posts I have in the specified category.

When I do a get_posts I'm using `posts_per_page => -1` but wordpress is still returning the same posts number 9 (It's my actual blog pages configuration).

**Query**

```
                $arg = [
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'post_per_page' => -1,
                    'post_status' => 'published',
                    'compare' => 'AND',
                    'meta_query' => [
                        'compare' => 'AND',
                        [
                            'key' => 'post_news_category_highlight',
                            'value' => $atts['category'],
                            'compare' => 'IN'
                        ],
                    ]
                ];
```

How can I retrieve the next elements page? I have to know total posts which have the main category.

Thanks

Jaster.

Comment: What happens with `$args=['posts_per_page'=>4];` does it still give 9 posts ? Note the status is usually `publish` not `published`. Remove the extra `compare` attribute outside the meta query. Maybe you have some plugins/theme interfering here?

Comment: I just put `posts_per_page => 4` and it returned me 9 posts again. I don't have other plugins enabled right now. @birgire

Comment: Any caching? it could also be something in your theme, that's modifying it.

Comment: in the text of your question you refer to 'posts_per_page', but in your code you have 'post_per_page' - is that just a typing mistake?

Answer (score -1):

I just use `'nopaging' => true` and it solves my problem.